# Specifying polygon face toward two different lines using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, streets, adjacency

I have a parcel layer, a street of city layer, and I want to find the parcels at the corner of two different streets (meaning a house with two faces toward 2 streets).

I am using ArcMap.

[image]

I want to find the parcels like the selected one, the red line is the center of street, the yellow one is the limit that people can build. I get the street name for the parcel by spatial joining the parcels layer and the streets layer, but the parcel at the corner of two streets is a special case, so I want to figure them to sign a coefficient.